# Partially transpose a table in BigQuery SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, pivot, transpose

I have a table that calculates revenues and costs like this :

| Project name | revenues | costs | margin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| Two | 10 | 3 | 7 |
| Three | 6 | 1 | 5 |

And need to transform the columns into additional rows, creating a unique column Money instead:

| Project name | type | Money |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | revenues | 3 |
| One | costs | 1 |
| One | margin | 2 |
| Two | revenues | 10 |
| Two | costs | 3 |
| Two | margin | 7 |
| Three | revenues | 6 |
| Three | costs | 1 |
| Three | margin | 5 |

What type of transposition / Pivoting should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select Project_name, type, Money
from your_table
unpivot (Money for type in (revenues, costs, margin))
```

If applied to sample data in your question  output is

[image]